# How would I compare a set of strings?

Tags: java, android

i have a username and a password string. How can I compare them in Android? This is somewhat what I'm looking for:

```
if( user== username && pass == password){ then do this  }
else if(user[does not equal to]username && pass==password{ toast (invaild username.)}
else if(user==username && pass[does not equal] password{toast(invaild password)}
else{ toast [invaild login]}
```

I know that's not correct coding but the two "else if" statements is what I'm looking for. The rest is just to give a better understanding of what I'm trying to do.

The username is what's entered into a Edittext same with the Password so they are both String when i .getText.toString right?

Comment: First of all: strings have to be compared using `.equals()`, not `==`. As to what I believe is your question: don't tell the user whether his username or password is wrong. If you do so, it will encourage people to guess a username + password combination. Just displaying 'invalid username/password' should be enough.

Comment: Good thought, this is for work tho and the people their wont really have the time nor the knowledge for a gussing game.

Comment: Okay, so what is it exactly you're asking?

Comment: If you care about security you should not store passwords...

Comment: Set of Strings was some Set<String> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare the text in strings use `equals()` e.g. `pass.equals(password)` rather than == which checks if two strings are the same object.

For "does not equal" you can negate the statement e.g. `!pass.equals(password)`.

Comment: This is not the issue at hand.

Comment: Doesnt that just check objects-ints not String's?

Comment: 1 moment, editing or deleting as necessary.

Comment: @DakotaMiller equals will work for comparing the values of the strings.

Comment: Ok i thought it was just for Object and ints.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html, the method is in there. However if you're not asking for the functionality to compare strings and I've misunderstood your question, then let me know and I'll happily remove this answer.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel If that was your downvote, do you think your comment still applies?

Comment: @splrs: it was indeed. I'm not sure anymore if it was warranted, I'll wait to see what Miller says. I'll retract it if this was the issue after all.

Comment: I agree that initially it was entirely justified, now I'm not sure it is following the edit. Obviously your call though.

Comment: Since your answer was accepted I'm guessing this was just another case of the duplicates. I retracted my downvote.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenVannevel, without the downvote I'd not have provided a useful answer, so it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pass.equal(password)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the equals method for comparing strings.

```
if( user.equals(username) && pass.equals(password))
{
    then do this 
}
else if(!user.equals(username) && pass.equals(password)
{  
 Toast.makeText(this,"invalid username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else if(user.equals(username) && !pass.equals(password))
{
Toast.makeText(this,"invalid password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
else{ 
Toast.makeText(this,"Invalid login",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `.equals(..)` to compare `Strings`.  Also, to do *not* logically, you can use `!`.

```
//define user, username
//define pass, password
if(user.equals(username) && pass.equals(password)){ 
    //then do this  
}
else if(!user.equals(username) && pass.equals(password)){
    //toast (invaild username.)
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "invalid username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else if(user.equals(username) && !pass.equals(password)){
    //toast(invaild password)
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "invalid password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else{ 
    //toast [invaild login]
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "invalid login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Here are some sources on `Toast`:

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-toast-example/

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html